# gae searchablemodel info

Tags: search, google-cloud-datastore

Does anyone know where I can find official documentation on how to use the SearchableModel feature in Google App Engine to perform searches on the datastore? The only information I was able to find was the new Search API for documents only and not individual datastore entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use this class. It is unsupported, undocumented and deprecated. Please use the supported (though currently experimental) full-text search facility instead.

Comment: Are you referring to this?  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/overview#Query_Language_Overview

It seems that you need to create a "document" to perform the search.  Would it be feasible to do this if I just want to create simple entries that contains people's names that I can search for?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was referring to.  If you have a simpler need, you can just use a StringListProperty -- this allows you to query for each individual name, exactly.